# Java How to determine Type of data coming into UDP server? XML Binary

Tags: java, udp

I have a UDP server listening. Clients can either send binary data or XML data (binary represented as xml for those quick to attack). What is the appropriate way of determining data types coming in?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a piece of metadata (*flag*, *header*) to differentiate between the two. One bit is enough. Higher level protocols use more verbose header to distinguish between different types, e.g. in HTTP:

```
Content-Type: application/xml
```

Of course in your case, because UDP packages are small and lightweight, just assume the first byte is the type discriminator. `0` - XML, `1` - binary.

Don't try to guess the content type by examining it. XML document and binary document are very different from statistical point of view, but it's just cumbersome and error-prone. Also I don't suggest *trying* to parse incoming data as XML and treating it as binary if it fails.

Comment: So in general there is no way of knowing what type of data your clients send you unless there is an acknowledgement scheme of some sort?

Comment: @Mrshll187: your client is sending you a bunch of bytes. It's up to you to figure out how to interpret it. That's why files have extensions (or magic values). Note that this is not really an acknowledgement - you just have to attach a piece of metadata in the beginning of transmission.

Answer (score 1):

Download JDOM and add it to the classpath of your client. On incoming data instantiate a `SAXBuilder` and try to build an XML document from it. If it fails, it's binary data you have.

```
...
SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
try {
   builder.build(/*data*/);
   // You have XML data
} catch (Exception e) {
   // You have binary data
}
```